# What is the difference between these two observational update models in an information filter?

Tags: linear-algebra, kalman-filter, numerical-models, nonlinear-dynamical-system

The Information Filter is defined as the mathematical inverse of the Kalman filter. As defined [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Information_filter), the observation update of the Information Matrix is defined as $$y_{k|k} = y_{k|k-1} + H^T_kR^{-1}_kz_k$$

This definition holds consistent in the article's source reference [here (pp 9, eq 55)](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/50572673/tutorialKF-with-cover-page-v2.pdf?Expires=1662214132&Signature=HPa9Es70TDeKG4tfnJxS0kIRBn1v8Sohbmnsp%7E2b2SQSUH1va03NsqcWMbxMph5EWcBWqM%7ElnRy5PXiB2dYSvSY8VKuCaQSoeiIlx0nKcOO6DomjjT8Qm9IYeTGv9ocX3TYRnAegqmfJ7PZAwgysdW7XeTkPuP1mAUtE3E8CqwgXhUWg5RhNEiZadzh5sYGXTJv8t4fFE73Mvd3qnMpE3Hp8FzEpfA-1sl%7EhTF8vIKK6P35kwAt6yX6w7ebrlFGkZO-i0DW5JDnS3H56xRedCXqqltNqbDXjPUU1LcyWrgxLH2xjKVy8y6ZRl9I1Xi7SGsXz3dgA4TJgxAFleTKKqg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA) and *that* source's reference [here (pp 264, table 6.20)](http://ee.hacettepe.edu.tr/%7Esolen/Matlab/MatLab/Matlab%20-%20Kalman%20filtering%20Theory%20and%20practice%20using%20MATLAB%202nd%20Edition.pdf).

Looking at some additional literature, this measurement function is sometimes defined differently. [This source on the Extended Information Filter (pp 698, eqn 18](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0278364904045479?casa_token=e3eYw4WCx3AAAAAA:wyDB8uk5VMvkrovZFvuconnjkTe5i99vsQRGy8n6PdJt6tP6OZj_xed8LT4uXQiu3Qy0RKy8VJRGRA) presents a definition (albeit in alternative symbols) that reads, once reordered and using the above standard symbol set, $$y_{k|k} = y_{k|k-1} + H^T_kR^{-1}_k(z_k - h(\bar X_{k|k-1}) + H_k\bar X_{k|k-1})$$

That is, the measurement is now a quantity of the measurement minus a non-linear prediction of the measurement from the state estimate plus a linear prediction of the measurement. The cited paper seems to describes this as a Gaussian approximation of a non-linear measurement.

What I'd like to know is:

What is the second form of the equation implying geometrically?
When is the appropriate time to use this second form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a partial answer to my own question.

$(z_k - h(\bar X_{k|k-1}) + H_k\bar X_{k|k-1})$ is the result of a Taylor Series Expansion which aims to linearize the residual calculation.

Edit:
I found [this set of lecture notes](https://faculty.cc.gatech.edu/%7Ebboots3/STR-Spring2018/Lectures/Lecture16/Lecture16_notes.pdf) (section 1.3) that dives into Taylor Series Expansion in the application of the Extended Kalman Filter. Essentially it strives to approximate the non-linear measurement model. Sections 1.5 also has some great commentary on applications and vulnerabilities.

This really helped me dig down into the performance of my residual calculation ($y = z - Hx$) and to look at what the components of the Tayler Series Expansion is supposed to do: add in an error approximation component to "make up for" the error in the "predicted measurement" $Hx$.

Ultimately, it seems my system was too nonlinear to get good approximations even with this technique. Examining the role of the risidual - to "steer" the Kalman gain towards the measurement or the model - helped me identify inductively how to structure the residual calculation.

Going to mark this as answered.